# Customizing the attachement page to show rest of all images in a gallery from post

Tags: images, attachments, gallery, attachment-fields-to-edit

How to customize the attachment image page with previous and next navigation button and show below rest images in a gallery ? I just added a visual representation

**Post page**

[image]

**Attachment page**

[image]